# Python source code recovery from exe

Tags: python, recovery

I had a python program written which I converted to an exe binary using py2exe. I have all of the files generated in the dist folder but due to a system crash, I lost the source code.

Is there a way to get the .py source code file back from .exe or other supporting files generated by py2exe?

Comment: Sam, that's unfortunate and I'm sorry but I don't know how to extract the code from a windows binary. However, man you need to do some source control (if you aren't already) and need to backup. As a developer/programmer/engineer/architect/etc., you HAVE to be paranoid and CYA.

Comment: After a system crash you could simply try to restore the files on your filesystem? E.g. by using testdisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Answer (score 5):

According to the following links, you can extract your `.pyc` files from `library.zip` and then use decompyle to obtain `.py` files similar to what you started with.

http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/101743-py2exe-there-way-go-backwards-exe2py

http://sourceforge.net/projects/decompyle/

Hope it works, and I hope you use github or bitbucket next time.

Comment: Decompiling python bytecode files is something of a black art though, I'm not aware of any really up-to-date projects that do this (decompyle for instance was last updated in 2009), so for modern Python versions, you'll have a hard time...