# Python Compilation to .exe

Tags: python-3.x, binary, exe

I am new to python and need to compile it into .exe version. My question is when a py script is compiled into .exe does it mean it cant decode anymore?

Our goal is make python scripts safe when deploying to client servers as we dont want them to get our source code using the .exe.

Answer (score 1):

No - a compiled piece of code is compiled into another language (byte code) - you can not actually read the source code.

Do have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260602/python-source-code-recovery-from-exe) though...

Comment: Thanks! this would add confidence to my project

Answer (score 1):

A savvy user who has this .exe version could extract the .pyc (byte code) and then break that down using a python decompiler like Uncompyle to get it pretty much back to source code. Thus there is a way (and a chance) of the python source code (close to it) getting extracting from your .exe version.

Comment: @j-squillaro i will take note on to this.