# How to get back source code files from any .exe file?

Tags: javascript, python, decompiler, hexdump, xxd

I have .exe file compiled from javascript and python. I would like to decompile it and get back the code.
I tried many python decompiler libraries but it doesn't work.
I tried using `hexdump` or `xxd` commands but I am new to it so I don't really know how to use them.

thanks (and sorry for english mistakes)

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260602/python-source-code-recovery-from-exe

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I don't have pyc files juste the .exe file.

Comment: Reverse engineering is not that easy. Do you know which tools were used to compile the executable?

Comment: No. Here is my problem. someone said me that hexdump should work but I don't know how it works.

Comment: don't expect one simple method for sources in different languages. Different languages may use different methods and tools to hide code. Popular tools which convert Python code to .exe create self-extracting .zip file and you can extract source code .py or bytes code .pyc. And when you run this .exe then you can even find temporary folder with .py or .pyc (which is deleted when you close program). But there are also tools which convert Python to C/C++ and then they compile it to machine code - and this may not ahve method to recreate Python code.